# Windows 10 Quick Assist 6 digit Security code

Tags: windows-10, remote-control, remote-assistance

Windows 10 Quick Assist uses 6 digit security code to identify a helper to a person being helped on intermediate Microsoft server so that IP connection can be established. Code is valid for 10 minutes. That means no more than 999,999 people across the whole world can use Quick Assist to give help within any given 10 minutes. This translates to 1,666 people/sec.

If I got this right - isn't this number really low considering how ubiquitous Windows is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I got this right - isn't this number really low considering how ubiquitous Windows is?

That would be 999,999 possible combinations specific moment in time, a code that is generated by a server, so it knows what are the active codes.

The minute the code is used to connect to somebody else, it's put back into the code rotation, and can be used again.  Since only a single person can connect, there isn't a pigeonhole issue, since again a server is likely generating the numbers.

It is worth pointing out, the entire thing is connected to your Microsoft Account, so there is most definitely a server backend.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think about the fact that most people will probably connect within a minute or less and then code will be reused.